# Rails.application.routes.url_helpers crashing Heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm building a [Serializer for Collection+Json](https://github.com/carlesjove/collection_json_serializer), and I'm writing an API as an example. I'm having an issue when using `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` on the deployed app on Heroku.

I use this in one serializer:

`Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.bills_url`

In development, everything works fine. However, on Heroku this raises an error:

`undefined method 'bills_url' for #<Module:0x007f3a1eab8d58> (NoMethodError)`.

If I dump `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.methods`, no `_url` or `_path` methods are listed. However, they are if I run the same code in the console:

```
heroku run rails c --app myapp
> Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.methods
> # => :bills_url is present
```

This is weird. Any clue on this? Does Heroku make `url_helpers` not available? I am absolutely lost. I've googled a lot but found nothing.

Here's the [bug report](https://github.com/carlesjove/collection_json_serializer/issues/38) for the complete trace.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem and found that is was caused due to 2 reasons:

First, using the Rails.application.routes.url_helpers methods in class constants like in the following snippet:

```
class myObject
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :id, :link

  DEFAULT_OBJECT = new id: 1, 
                     link: Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.my_object_url({:id => 1})

   ...
end
```

Second, setting `config.eager_load = true` in the environment file.

So result being, when `config.eager_load = true`, the dynamic url helpers haven't been registered when the myObject class is loaded.

This article maybe useful -> http://blog.arkency.com/2014/11/dont-forget-about-eager-load-when-extending-autoload/

Answer (score 3):

Craig's answer is on the right track.  So, because in `config/environments/production.rb` we have

```
config.eager_load = true
```

We also need to add the following:

```
config.before_eager_load do
  Rails.application.reload_routes!
end
```

Now anywhere in your code, you should be able to use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.*_path` and `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.*_url` helpers.

In my case, I was trying to use the helpers in concerns, and having the same issue you were.  This works like a charm on heroku in production for me... of course it took me way too long to work it out! ;)