# Custom validation message (in model file) that includes a path not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, model

In the user model file I have included:

```
validates :email,  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, message: "You can reset your password " + link_to("here", new_password_reset_path) }
```

On loading the page on the development server, this generates the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `new_password_reset_path' for #<Class:0x007f4d36863460>
```

The alternative code below has the same result/error message.

```
validates :email,  uniqueness: { message: "You can reset your password #{link_to("here", new_password_reset_path)}" }
```

Is it not possible to refer to a path in the model file? If not, how could I implement the intended here?

---

**Update:** At first it seemed that the solutions that included `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in the model file worked. And indeed in development they worked. However, as it turned out, they don't work in production. They crash the site on Heroku. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135924/rails-application-routes-url-helpers-crashing-heroku-app) post also seems to refer to something similar and seems to indicate that you should not use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in a model file. After pushing to Heroku, when I try to open the website it says "Application Error". So I checked the heroku logs and found:

```
app[web.1]: [3] ! Unable to load application: NoMethodError: undefined method `new_password_reset_path' for #<Module:0x007f7392350b08>
app[web.1]: /app/app/models/user.rb:32:in `<class:User>': undefined method `new_password_reset_path' for #<Module:0x007f7392350b08> (NoMethodError)
```

Does anyone have an alternative solution that also works on Heroku / in production? *That is, a solution how to include an url/path in a custom validation message in the model file.*

Comment: I guess you will have to include url_helper in your model 
`class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end`

Comment: I added `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` at the beginning of the model file. But I still got the same error message (also after restarting the server).

Comment: which rails version are you using?

Comment: I'm using rails 4.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. I hope this will help.

**config/locales/en.yml**

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        email: 'You can reset your password <a href="%{link}">here</a>.'
```

In **User** Model.

```
validates :email,  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, message: I18n.t("activerecord.errors.messages.email", link: Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.new_password_reset_url) }
```

Comment: It indeed gets rid of the error message. Only the link is shows as flat text: "You can reset your password <a href="/password_resets/new">here</a>." So it's not a working link.

Comment: @Nick You can append `.html_safe` to the error message in your view file to show the unescaped text/link.

Comment: Yes, adding `.html_safe` to the shared error messages view and using `new_password_reset_path` (not `url` which gave other errors) in the model file worked!

Comment: Another implementation that doesn't require changes in en.yml nor does it require `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in the model file, would be: `uniqueness: { message: "You can reset your password <a href='#{Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.new_password_reset_path}'>here</a>.".html_safe }`

Comment: As it turns out, including `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in the model file doesn't work. it works in development but crashes Heroku. See the update added to the original post.

Comment: you have used `new_password_reset_url` or `new_password_reset_path` on heroku?

Comment: I used `path` (since that worked in development and `url` didn't). But I now also tested for `url` in production and that generates a similar error message in Heroku's logs: `undefined method 'new_password_reset_url'`.

Comment: please add this `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` on the top in your model and try

Comment: please post your routes file

Comment: In my routes I have: `resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]` (remember, it does work in development, and the post I refer to in the update in the original post seems to suggest you simply cannot have `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` in the model file, meaning a different direction for a solution is required).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. Thank you for pointing me there. The solution they suggest there is an [initializer](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/647#issuecomment-75149459). They also expect that this bug will be solved with the release of Ruby 2.3.